# Angular JS translate not working properly inside Visualforce page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, visualforce, angular-translate

I need to translate my HTML into different languages based on user preference. For that, I am using Angular JS translate method. The example when I write inside notepad and saved as ".html" is working fine. But when I pasted the same code inside my Salesforce Visualforce page, its behavior changes.ie. When I click on the button"IT" to translate the content to "Italics" the contents are translating to Italics but within seconds the contents are again going back to their preferred language "EN". I have given below my screenshot of output.

[image]

I have given below my code, can anyone say what's wrong in this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="app">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.5.2/angular-translate.js"></script>
 <script>
 // Code goes here
 var app = angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

 app.config(['$translateProvider',
 function($translateProvider) {

 $translateProvider.translations('it', {
  'Purchase order': "Ordine di acquisto ",
  'Number:': "Numero:",
  'Customer data': "Dati Cliente",
  'Surname / Company':"Cognome/Società",
  'Name':"Nome",
  'Piazza way':"Via/Piazza",
  'City':"Città",
  'VAT tax code':"Codice Fiscale/Partita IVA",
  'Phone':"Telefono",
  'E-Mail':"E-Mail",
  'CAP':"CAP"


});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");
 }
]);

app.controller('AppController', function ($translate) {
// this.browser = navigator.userAgent;
 this.useLang = function (lang) {
$translate.use(lang);
}
});
</script>


 <div ng-controller="AppController as app">
 <h3 translate>     Purchase order </h3>
 <p translate>Number:</p>
 <h3 translate>Customer data</h3>
 <p><span translate>Surname / Company</span>_________</p>
 <p> <span translate>Name</span>__________</p>
 <p><span translate>Piazza way</span>____________</p>
 <p><span translate>CAP</span>_______<span translate>City</span>______</p>
 <p><span translate>VAT tax code</span>__________</p>
 <p><span translate>Phone</span>____________</p>
 <p><span translate>E-Mail</span>_________</p>

 <button ng-click="app.useLang('it')">IT</button>
 <button ng-click="app.useLang('en')">EN</button>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: When I run this code as is in a snippet or plunker it works just fine, sounds like you have some other code that is triggering the switch back to english in the angular loop. Put some debugging around your preferred language code in your full application.

Comment: Oaky will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the solutions provided in developer forums, finally I found the solution for my problem. Actually the reason behind my content going back to "english" from "italics" is "page refreshing". To stop the page from refreshing I need to set the `<button>` type as "button".
             ie     `<button type="button">`

**Code change**

`<button type="button" ng-click="app.useLang('it')">IT</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="app.useLang('en')">EN</button>`
I did the change in my code and it stopped the page from refreshing, which in turn gave my expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

{{'variable_name' | translate }}

Comment: Your solution is not displaying anything

Comment: try<p> {{translations.variablename}}</p>

Comment: first Install module via Bower:

$ bower install angular-translate  then try <p>{{ 'Number' | translate }}</p>